# How to use Typescript definitions imported as `* as`

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using `react-icons` and trying to import all icon definitions as `import * as Icons from 'react-icons/fi'` 
The question is how can I create a type that should be one of the types exported from Icons

e.g. I am trying to make props interface like this:

```
interface Props {
   icon: Icons // don't know what to do here
}
```

This is how the `react-icons/fi/index.d.ts` file looks like:

```
export declare const FiActivity: IconType;
export declare const FiAirplay: IconType;
export declare const FiAlertCircle: IconType;
export declare const FiAlertOctagon: IconType;
export declare const FiAlertTriangle: IconType;
export declare const FiAlignCenter: IconType;
.....
```

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you want the names of all the Icon constants in the `Icons` namespace, as the type of all Icons seems to be the same `IconType`.

In that case, you can use a combination of `keyof` and `typeof` to achieve that:

```
import * as Icons from 'react-icons/fi'

interface Props {
   icon: keyof typeof Icons
}
```

`typeof` will get you the type of the Icons. `keyof` then returns the name of the keys of that type as a union type. So the type you are getting will end up being `'FiActivity' | 'FiAirplay' | 'FiAlertCircle' | ...`.

If you wanted to accept any of those consts as a whole as prop, and not just the name, then you can just use `IconType` directly.

```
import * as Icons from 'react-icons/fi';
import {IconType} from 'react-icons';

interface Props {
   icon: IconType
}
```